# Proper way to Implement a FileWatcher in a multithreading program C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

- I have a multi-threaded program (3-4 threads). All the threads depend on a couple of parameters which are specified in an XML file.
- Since the parameters in the XML file may be changed at any time by a user therefore, the different threads need to be notified about it and need to get the updated copy of parameters.
- To monitor the changes in the XML file, I am using a `FileWatcher` as per the MSDN documentation.

  ```
  clas  ReadXML
  {
  //parameters
  private static string Param1 = "";
  private static string Param2 = "";


  public static void ReadXmlParameters()
  {
      XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
      try
      {
          xDoc.Load(_ParameterFileDirrectory + @"\" + _ParameterFileDirrectory);

          //parameters
          Param1 = (xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Parameters/SetOne/IpAddress")).InnerText;
          Param2 = (xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Parameters/SetOne/Username")).InnerText;                
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
      } 
  }


  public static void CreateXMLWatcher()
  {
      try
      {
          // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
          FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
          watcher.Path = _ParameterFileDirrectory;
          /* Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and 
             the renaming of files or directories. */
          watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
             | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
          // Only watch .xml files.
          watcher.Filter = _ParameterFileFilename; // "ParameterFile.xml";

          // Add event handlers.
          watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
          watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
          watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
          watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

          // Begin watching.
          watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
      }
  }

  // Define the event handlers.
  private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
  {
      // Specify what is done when a file is "Changed", "Created", or "Deleted".
      Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);

      if (e.ChangeType.ToString() == "Changed")
      {
          ReadXmlParameters(); //Read the Parameters from XML again

          MyThreadClass1._waitTillParametersChange.Set(); //Notifying the thread that the parameters might have chnaged

      }

  }

  }
  ```

  The above implementation is working fine for me. I have to start the FileWatcher from the Main() using the following lines:

  ```
  public static void Main()
  {
      ReadXml.ReadXmlParameters();        
      ReadXml.CreateXMLWatcher();

      // Start other threads now
  }
  ```

and then I start my other threads.

**QUESTION:** Since with the above-mentioned implementation, I have got Static methods and variables in my program so, I am wondering if this is the proper (at least acceptable) implementation of a `FileWatcher` or should I try to get rid of these static things by implementing `ReadXml` as a singleton class (or providing the same object to all the thread classes).

Comment: Remove the threads, use an ActionBlock<T> that receives the FileSystemEventArgs data and performs any required processing on its action. An ActionBlock already has an input buffer and by default processes only one message at a time. You can create a pipeline of blocks if you want

Comment: BTW, FSW will drop events if the event hanlder isn't fast enough. Processing the data inside the event can lead to event loss if a lot of changes happen at once

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Threads are not really waiting for the file to get changed. They are just affected if the file gets changed. for example, one thread is responsible to transfer files to an FTP server and keep doing its job but if the Ip Address changes then, it need to take the new IP address.

Comment: Another problem - the FSW is a local variable which means it can be garbage collected. You don't need any of those static methods, they could be a single action in the method itself. The FSW though should be a field

Comment: Singleton is no different from static class, at least in this case. Just define event on your `ReadXml` class, subscribe to this event from threads, and fire this event when something changes. This will be not ideal but "good enough".

Comment: @skm in this case you should be looking at async operations. Anyway, I'd use a pipeline of blocks to receive the change notification and start processing changes. You could have a pipeline of TransformBlock classes, where the first receives the event and reloads the parameters and sends the new params to the second block. Second block talks to the FTP server and sends the results to the third block etc.

Comment: That's similar to what powershell does. Each command in a pipeline runs on a separate thread, receives messages from the previews command and sents results to the next

Comment: @Evk, and Panagiotis: Could you pls add a little sample.